# What is the wrong with Scope_Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I tried milions of methods to make scope identity work. It is just returns __Page !!

```
Query = "INSERT INTO seekers(name,sname,lname,status,gender,dob,major,experince,email,password,phone,valid,city) values(@name,@sname,@lname,@status,@gender,@dob,@major,@exp,@email,@password,@phone,0,@city);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

// setting up command definition
Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);

// setting up command parameters
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", txt_email.Text);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", lst_gender.SelectedValue);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", lst_status.SelectedValue);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("phone", long.Parse("968" + txt_phone.Text));
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", txt_password.Text);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("exp", lst_exp.SelectedValue);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("city", lst_exp.SelectedValue);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("major", lst_major.SelectedValue);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txt_name.Text);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("sname", txt_sname.Text);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", txt_lname.Text);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", cld_birth.SelectedDate);

int ID = (int)Command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: with  `ExecuteScalar` , you cannot execute Select statments.

Comment: see this example here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx  Its work for me with ExecuteScalar.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by returns `__Page` but are there any insert triggers on the table? Also the table does definitely have an identity column?

Answer (score 0):

Try Out Parameter as follow...

```
Query = "INSERT INTO seekers(name,sname,lname,status,gender,dob,major,experince,email,password,phone,valid,city) values(@name,@sname,@lname,@status,@gender,@dob,@major,@exp,@email,@password,@phone,0,@city);SET @ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY();"

//Your Parameters..
SqlParameter ID=new SqlParameter();
ID.Name="@ID";
ID.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
Command.Parameters.Add(ID);
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int id=(int)ID.Value;
```

or
Tryb to Cast Output as follow...

```
 Query = "INSERT INTO seekers(name,sname,lname,status,gender,dob,major,experince,email,password,phone,valid,city) values(@name,@sname,@lname,@status,@gender,@dob,@major,@exp,@email,@password,@phone,0,@city);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);"

 int id= (Int32)Command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

SCOPE_IDENTITY will return a decimal, try:

```
int ID = (int) (decimal) Command.ExecuteScalar();
```

It's not very clear what you mean by:

> It is just returns __Page !!

Presumably the posted code is throwing an exception, and that's resulting in some higher level code doing whatever it is you mean by "... returns __Page".

If you look at the exception details, you'll find more about what happened: which I suspect is an `InvalidCastException` because you're trying to cast the object returned by Command.ExecuteScalar (a boxed decimal) to an int.

Answer (score 0):

use set nocount off and try

As First execute statement is insert the returned value is number of records effected